# How can I call a $scope variable inside function to different templates in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have 2 templates in ionic that have the same `ng-controller`. In the first template, I'm able to call `{{answer}}` that is declared in the function, but when I try to call it in the second template it doesn't show.

Here are the sample code:

**1st. Template**

```
<ion-view view-title="calculator" ng-controller="calcCtrl">
<input type="number" ng-model="num1">
<input type="number" ng-model="num2">
<button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="addition(num1, num2)">
  Add
</button>
<h2>Answer: {{answer}}</h2>
```

**2nd. Template**

```
<ion-view view-title="Add" ng-controller="calcCtrl">
   {{answer}}
</ion-view>
```

**JS file:**

```
app.controller("calcCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.addition = function(num1, num2) {
    $scope.answer = num1 + num2;
  }
});
```

How can I call the output for `{{answer}}` in my 2nd. template?

Comment: did you want to see the result on same time or after click and route on template 2 ?

Comment: after click and route to template 2

Comment: in this case are you sure your scope already exist to bind in another template?

Comment: @hazimIskandar In your case, when you route to template2, controller is reinitialized hence you can't see the `answer`.

Comment: u have  to pass the num1 and num2 to the template2 with out that how it will be work

Comment: @Maher I'm only declare the scope inside the function inside the same controller. Is there any other scope I should declare?

Comment: @gayathri how to pass the num1 and num2 inside the template2? can you help show it to me

Comment: You need to use a service to share data through. Each `ng-controller` will create new instance

Comment: @Ricky how can I route to template2 without reinitialized the controller?

Comment: you can pass it in url route as stateParams, or you can keep it in localstorage and one thing you can use $emit

Comment: @Maher you can only use event  if both controllers are active. Not really clear where these templates exist...same route/state or not

Comment: @charlietfl, are you sure we can't use emit when our controllers inside one module ? actually emit will be remove when page is refreshing

Comment: @charlietfl is not on the same route.

Comment: @hazimIskandar, 1 question why you used controllers with same names in your app? : ))

Comment: @hazimIskandar the proper thing to do is store the data in a service. An event definitely won't work for an instance that doesn't exist yet and although you can use rootScope it is highly discouraged

Comment: i choose first option...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are very close to get the answer. The problem is in your controller you have not defined $scope. answer
Just make this correction and try now.....

```
enter code here

app.controller("calcCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.answer=0;
  $scope.addition = function(num1, num2) {
    $scope.answer = num1 + num2;
  }
});
```

Now when the value of answer will be changed it will be updated in DOM.